# Symfony2, AWS Beanstalk: how to push vendor as files not git-submodules to repo

Tags: git, symfony, amazon-web-services, git-submodules, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are using Symfony2 on a AWS Beanstalk Application. For the Deployment we adjusted the Deployment-Script to do a *composer install* after the application has been uploaded.

Eventhough this works theoretically, it has some downsides - mainly the constantly increasing deployment-time (which sometimes results in server timeouts) and increasing dependencies on the availability of other servers.

I have read that some people copy the `vendor/*` to a tmp-dir and move it back after the deployment to [speed-up the deployment](https://github.com/spy23/AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-deployment-scripts-for-Symfony2-applications).

It's definetely helpful but we are updating our `composer.json` quite often so we still have to have a *composer install* in our deployment-process. We believe that the best approach is to include all dependencies (`vendor/*`) as files in the repo and skip the *composer install* during the deployment.

Unfortunately most libraries are included as git-submodules and AWS does not support submodules (all files have to be in the repo).

**So here comes my question:**

*What is the best way to remove all git-submodules and commit the real files instead?*

I have tried combining:

```
git submodules --recursive foreach
```

with [How do I remove a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule) but without succes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this workflow:

- create a new release folder
- checkout the latest version of your code in the new folder
- copy "vendor" from the currently active release folder into new release folder
- run "composer.phar install"

This way, composer will only update the libraries that have changed between releases.

I use it successfully with [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki) (there is also a Symfony specific version called [capifony](http://capifony.org/)) that can help you out. Especially because it can keep a clone of your git repository so pushing out new releases is much faster, and deployments and rollbacks are one-liner away.